# Method to add the even/odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with several numbers:

```
int[] tab = {1,2,3,4};
```

I have to create two methods the first is the **sum()** method and the second is **numberOdd()**.

It's Ok for this step !

```
int length = tab.length;
length = numberOdd(tab,length);

int sum_odd = sum(tab, length);

System.out.println(" 1) - Calculate the sum of the odds numbers :  => " + sum_odd);


public static int sum(int[] tab, int length){
      int total = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        total += tab[i];
      }
      return total;
}


public static int numberOdd(int[] tab, int length){
      int n = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(tab[i] % 2 != 0){
          tab[n++] = tab[i];
        }
      }
      return n; 
}
```

Now, I have to add the even numbers with the **numberEven()** method and I get the value "0".

I don't understand why I retrieve the value => 0 ???????

Here is my code:

```
int[] tab = {1,2,3,4};

int length = tab.length;
length = numberOdd(tab,length);

int sum_odd = sum(tab, length);

length = numberEven(tab,length);
int sum_even = sum(tab, length);



System.out.println(" 1) - Calculate the sum of the odds numbers :  => " + sum_odd);
System.out.println(" 2) - Calculate the sum of the evens numbers :  => " + sum_even);
}

public static int numberEven(int[] tab, int length){
      int n = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(tab[i] % 2 == 0){
          tab[n++] = tab[i];
        }
      }
      return n; 
}
```

For information: I share the code here => https://repl.it/repls/CriminalAdolescentKilobyte

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're mutating `tab` in `numberOdd()`, so you're not running `numberEven()` against the array you think you are.

Comment: Also, why are you modifying the length, and why are you even passing the length as argument to your methods? Use array.length to get the length of an array. No need to pass an additional argument.

Comment: Thank you, I understood my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add `tab[i]` to `n`
2. Having `length` as a parameter to `numberEven` does not cause any harm but you don't need it.

Given below is the working example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tab = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        System.out.println(numberEven(tab));
    }

    public static int numberEven(int[] tab) {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            if (tab[i] % 2 == 0) {
                n += tab[i];
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understood my problem. ^^

Answer (score 1):

you have changed the array in your numberOdd() method.
try replacing `tab[n++] = tab[i];`  with `n++;`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int sumEven(int[] tab){
  int sumEven = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
    if(tab[i] % 2 == 0){
      sumEven = sumEven + tab[i];
    }
  }
  return sumEven; 
}
```

This should work.